# VBA Value from ComboBox to range (cell to last column)

Tags: vba, combobox, range

I have a code written:

```
'Declare variables
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Paste values to sheet
Worksheets("Machine Format").Select
With Worksheets("Machine Format")
Range("C15", .Cells(15, LastColumn)).Value = UserForm_TFVPM.SealingMethod_ComboBox.Text
End With
```

And it is meant to take a value from a combobox and paste that value to a range that's C15 to last column judging by row 1 (up to first blank cell in row 1 which determines the last column)

And the problem with this code is that it pastes the value in every column row 15, even A15 and B15. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Could someone, please, assist me with this one?

Comment: Check the value of `LastColumn`. It is probably 1. You should specify a sheet.

Comment: I have multiple sheets in my workbook and they are all symmetrical in that sense (all data I need to work with starts on column C)